# execute bash script asynchronously multiple times?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have this bash script

```
# a.sh

name="Hello"
echo $name
```

How can I execute multiple times `a.sh` asynchronously?

Comment: You can add `&`: `./a.sh &`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Bash range expansion and `for` loop to conveniently express the multiplicity, and the `&` operator to put the script executions in the background:

```
for x in {1..8}; do
    bash /path/to/a.sh &
done
```